# Verify whether s list of number is part of the fibonacci series

Tags: python, list, function, fibonacci

I have made a function which takes a list as an input and returns a list too.

e.g. input is `[4,6,8,10,12]`
and output should be  `[0,0,1,0,0]`

because 8 belongs in fibonacci series

my code is

```
for i in input1:
    phi=0.5+0.5*math.sqrt(5.0)
    a=phi*i
    out =[ i == 0 or abs(round(a) - a) < 1.0 / i];
    return out;
```

Comment: What's the problem you are facing exactly?

Comment: You don't need semicolons at the end of lines.

Comment: I have a function  which takes input as list of numbers and should return the output is list as well, input1=[4,6,8,10,12] and it should return [0,0,1,0,0] because 8 belongs in fib series and rest dont

Comment: Here is a working shorter version of your code: `phi=0.5+0.5*math.sqrt(5.0)` and then `out = [1 if abs(round(phi*i) - phi*i) < (1/i) else 0 for i in input1]` using list comprehension. I replaced `a` by `phi*i`. If something unclear, feel free to ask

Comment: it returns 0 0 0 0 0  only

Comment: @Bazingaa this `if/else`is cumbersome, you can convert `True` and `False` to `1` and `0` respectively, with `int()`

Comment: Thanks for the help,  had u posted it 4-5 minutes earlier I could have passed my assessment at office :)

Comment: You are using python 2 I guess. Then you needed `(1.0/i)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will work:

```
input1 = [4,6,8,10,12]
out=[]
for i in input1:
    phi=0.5+0.5*math.sqrt(5.0)
    a=phi*i
    out.append(i == 0 or abs(round(a) - a) < 1.0 / i);
```

To convert bool to int

```
import numpy
y=numpy.array(out)
new_output = y*1
```

Comment: Print your out and compare it to the OP's desired output. Do you get the same format of output? I don't

Comment: Can you make it 0 and 1 for the sake of OP

Comment: @MahinMalhotra: Try my answer in the comments above

Answer (score 0):

I would think that the best way is probably to write a function called `is_fibonacci`, which takes a numerical input and returns `True` if the input is a fibonacci number, otherwise `False`. Then you can just do a list comprehension on your initial list `input1`: `return [1 if is_fibonacci(num) else 0 for num in input1]`. (Of course, `is_fibonacci` could automatically return `1` or `0` instead of a Boolean, in which case the list comprehension is even simpler.)

Writing the `is_fibonacci` function is an interesting exercise that I will leave to you :) (But happy to help if you are struggling with it.)

Answer (score 0):

This should solve I guess

```
import math


# A function that returns true if x is perfect square
def isPerfectSquare(x):
    s = int(math.sqrt(x))
    return s * s == x


# Returns true if n is a Fibinacci Number, else false

def isFibonacci(n):
    return isPerfectSquare(5 * n * n + 4) or isPerfectSquare(5 * n * n - 4)


i = [4, 6, 8, 10, 12]
print(i)
j = []
# A utility function to test above functions
for item in i:
    if (isFibonacci(item) == True):
        j.append(1)

    else:
        j.append(0)
print(j)
```

Output:

```
[4, 6, 8, 10, 12] 
[0, 0, 1, 0, 0]
```

Answer (score 0):

This does what you want

```
def isFibonaccy(inputList):
    out = []
    for i in inputList:
        phi = 0.5 + 0.5 * math.sqrt(5.0)
        a = phi * i
        out.append(int(i == 0 or abs(round(a) - a) < 1.0 / i))

    return out

print(isFibonaccy([4, 6, 8, 10, 12])) # -> [0, 0, 1, 0, 0]
```